# rational parameterization of quartic

Tags: number-theory, rational-functions

With the curve $x^4 - 6x^2 - y^2 + 1 = 0$ in the range of $x$ inside of $(-1,1)$, I can only identify two rational points $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$.  Is it possible to determine if there are others?

Comment: have you graphed the curve on this domain?

Comment: Yes.   It looks like an oval.  Its x values are actually all between $1-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}-1$

Comment: Your curve is the double covering of $\mathbb{P}^1$ ramified over four points: $x^2=3\pm 2\sqrt{2}$, so it is of genus $1$. Hence, there is no "rational parametrization". However, it is probably possible to give the list of all rational points using the theory of elliptic curves.

Comment: Does that mean there are a finite number of rational points on the curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=1$;
$B=0$;
$C=-6$;
$D=0$;
$q=1$;
$Q=2$;

then let
$x = (Q(X+C)-D^2/Q)/Y$

$y = -q + x(xX-D)/Q$

$x = 2/YX - 12/Y$

$y = 2X^3/Y^2 - 24X^2/Y^2 + 72X/Y^2 - 1$

then using Ian Conell's quartic to cubic reduction formuli[ref]
we obtain an elliptic curve

(1)  $y^2 = x^3 - 6x^2 - 4x + 24$

Running mwrank shows that

Regulator = 1

The rank and full Mordell-Weil basis have been determined unconditionally.
[[0],[]]

(0.020706 seconds)

Answer: There are no rational points on the curve other than those you
already found. There are 2 affine points at infinity [1:1:0] and [1:-1:0] for the quartic, but you probably are not interested in them.

ref: https://ask.sagemath.org/question/50319/i-have-the-hyperelliptic-curve-y2x4814731024x2-1-how-do-i-convert-this-curve-to-an-elliptic-curve-in-a-short-weierstrass-form/

Comment: Great answer but please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You curve is an *elliptic curve* over $\mathbb Q$, written in *Jacobi quartic* form.

The standard form for an elliptic curve is Weierstrass cubic form.

It is fairly straightforward to convert from one to the other.  If you do this with
your curve, you will get a Weierstrass cubic whose coefficients are small enough that it will be listed on standard tables, and then you can look it up and find out
how many rational points it has.

I can't do this for you at the moment; perhaps someone else will post an answer doing it.  It is fairly easy to do in any case, and I would guess that SAGE can make these sorts of conversions.